# How to assign values to the variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variables, variable-assignment

I have created a variable vector of 2*2 size and i am trying to assign some values to them and use them further in my programme, but i am not sure how to do it

```
Rho= sym('Rh0',[2,2]);
abc= [1 2; 5 6];
```

what i expect in the out put is

```
Rho1_1=1
Rho1_2=2
Rho2_1=5
Rho2_2=6
```

can some one help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works; using `num2cell` to convert the array to a cell array, and then use multiple indexing to 'deal' the variables with the content of the cell array:

```
clear
clc

abc= [1 2; 5 6];

abcCell = num2cell(abc'); %// Note the transpose; needed to get correct order.

[Rho1_1, Rho1_2,Rho2_1,Rho2_2] = abcCell{:}
```

Giving this:

```
Rho1_1 =

     1


Rho1_2 =

     2


Rho2_1 =

     5


Rho2_2 =

     6
```

Comment: Thank you @Benoit. but if i have something like 625 variables i have to literally type them to execute the 'deal' command ? i.e., 3rd line of your code. Cant i specify directly a vector in the left hand side to assign some values to this vector of 625 variables ?

Comment: mhh then it be be a bit more complicated yes. You might want to look into dynamic field indexing using structures, or maybe a regular loop would do the job. Without more info about your data it's a bit hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
rho = sym('r',[2,2]);
r1_1 = 1;
r1_2 = 2;
r2_1 = 5;
r2_2 = 6;
subs(rho)
```

spits out

```
ans =

     1     2
     5     6
```